# Unable to send keys to the text box in Selenium Web Driver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, textbox

I want to send keys to the text area but I am not able to send the keys. It shows error as `Element must not be hidden, disabled or read-only`

My code is

```
IWebElement userid = FamosDriver.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("SMSBody"));
                userid.SendKeys("Test");
```

Please let me know, how to send keys to the text area. its a blocker for me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The exception message states why you cannot call `SendKeys(...)`. Most likely there is a race condition between Selenium and JavaScript executing on the page. The solution is to use an [explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) before calling `SendKeys(...)`:

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(FamosDriver.WebDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var userid = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(ById("SMSBody")));

userid.SendKeys("test");
```

The assumption is if you wait until you can click the element, then you can interact with it in other ways.

Comment: It is not passing the arguments. Still the passing arguments is not showing in UI. I don't know why the text is showing. pls help on this

Comment: You will need to add more information to your question. See [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405792/3092298).